# Cannot read contents of file

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am trying to learn assembly, so far I have only used high level languages like c or java.
I looked back through a few assignments from last year in c and one of them was to make a command line hangman game, so I thought that I would try to implement this in assembly. I am trying to read a .txt file, but don't seem to be getting it to work right. For testing purposes I just want to print the file straight out to terminal, but for some reason sys_read fails.

Here is the code:

```
SYS_EXIT equ 1                          ; UNIX system call sys_exit
SYS_READ equ 3                          ; UNIX System call sys_read
SYS_WRITE equ 4                         ; UNIX System call sys_write
SYS_OPEN equ 5                          ; UNIX System call sys_open

STDIN equ 0                             ; File descriptor for Standard in stream
STDOUT equ 1                            ; File descriptor for Standard out stream

; print to standard out macro
    %macro print 2
        pushad                          ; Save all regisers
        mov eax, SYS_WRITE              ; Write system call
        mov ebx, STDOUT                 ; File descriptor for stdout
        mov ecx, %1                     ; Message to print as argument 1
        mov edx, %2                     ; Message length as argument 2
        int 0x80                        ; Call kernel
        popad                           ; restore all registers
    %endmacro

; print string to standard out macro
    %macro print_str 1
        section .data
            %%str db %1                 ; adress to hold string
            %%strL equ $ - %%str        ; length of string
        section .text   
            print %%str, %%strL         ; print string to stdout using print macro
    %endmacro

; print newline
    %macro println 0        
        section .data           
            %%strln db 0xA, 0xD         ; adress to hold newline and carrige return
        section .text
            print %%strln, 2            ; print newline
    %endmacro

; print string with trailing newline
    %macro print_str_ln 1
        section .data
            %%str db %1                 ; adress to hold string
            %%strL equ $ - %%str        ; length of string
        section .text   
            print %%str, %%strL         ; print string to stdout using print macro
            println                     ; prints newline
    %endmacro

; exit program
    %macro exit 1
        mov eax, SYS_EXIT               ; Exit system call
        mov ebx, $1                     ; Return value
        int 0x80                        ; call kernel
    %endmacro

section .text
    global _start                       ; Required for linker (ld)
_start:                                 ; Linker entry point
    print_str_ln "Welcome to hangman"   ; print message to user
    println                             ; print newline
    call open_file                      ; open file and read
    exit 0                              ; exit program

; Open the words list file
open_file:
    mov eax, SYS_OPEN                   ; System call open
    mov ebx, word_source_file           ; Points to filepath
    xor ecx, ecx                        ; O_RDONLY
    xor edx, edx                        ; mode is ignored when O_CREATE isn't specified
    int 0x80                            ; call kernel
    test eax, eax                       ; check output of SYS_OPEN
    jns read_file                       ; If sign flag set, read file
    print_str_ln "Could not open file"  ; Print error message to user
    exit 1                              ; exit program

; read the file that was opened
read_file:
    mov ebx, eax                        ; move file descriptor from eax to ebx
    mov eax, SYS_READ                   ; system call SYS_READ
    mov ecx, buffer                     ; The buffer
    mov edx, bufferlen                  ; The length of the buffer
    int 0x80                            ; call kernel
    test eax, eax                       ; check for errors
    jz split_words                      ; If EOF return
    print_str_ln "Counld not read file" ; Print error message
    js exit 1                           ; If read faild exit

; TESTING - Print contentsof buffer
split_words:
    mov edx, eax                        ; The amount of bytes read, returned from sys_read
    mov eax, SYS_WRITE                  ; System call sys_write
    mov ebx, STDOUT                     ; File descriptor (stdout)
    mov ecx, buffer                     ; The buffer
    int 0x80                            ; call kernel
    ret                                 ; return


section .bss
    buffer resb 2048                    ; A 2kb buffer ussed to read

section .data
bufferlen dw 2048                       ; The length of buffer
newline db 0xA, 0xD                     ; Newline and carrige return
word_source_file db 'words.txt', 0      ; The path to the words file
```

Now when I use the assembler and linker and run I get:

```
$ nasm -f elf hangman.asm
$ ld -m elf_i386 -o hangman hangman.o
$ ./hangman 
Welcome to hangman

Counld not read file
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'm still very new to assembly. 
Thank you for the help.

Comment: What happens if you give it the full path to the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn to use a debugger so you can fix your own mistakes. In this case however, the printed error message exactly pinpoints the problem location so you can do it in your head even by just re-reading your own comments:

```
test eax, eax                       ; check for errors
jz split_words                      ; If EOF return
print_str_ln "Counld not read file" ; Print error message
js exit 1                           ; If read faild exit
```

Obviously the read resulted in something other than zero which you consider an error. It is not an error, the system call returns the number of bytes read. But of course you already know that, given the code block at `split_words`.

Long story short: you probably want `jnz split_words` instead of `jz split_words`. In the long run you will likely need multiple `read` calls to fill the buffer repeatedly.